# how to use the drawimage () method with double parameters

Tags: java, graphics, draw, paintcomponent, drawimage

For example to draw a rectangle on a canvas I use Rectangle2D.Double, but I need to draw images with double type parameters. That's possible? since it only accepts parameters of type int..

Comment: Since the `drawImage` API only allows `int` parameters, no.  `AffineTransform` allows you to translate the origin point using double's, so, technically, you could translate the context with the specified values and then draw the image at `0x0` - just don't forget to reset the transformation

Comment: Round the double value to the nearest integer then cast it to an int like so `(int) myDouble`.

Comment: Use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676909/drawing-an-image-using-sub-pixel-level-accuracy-using-graphics2d

Answer (score 1):

Use an [`AffineTransform` translate instance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#getTranslateInstance%28double,%20double%29).  They can work with double values.  The resulting image drawing will then be 'dithered' along the edges to show what appears to be 'sub pixel accuracy' rendering.